# How can I find an element without an ID in HTML for VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The aim is to write login and password to a website through VBA code. I stucked on lines without id.

Below is the part of HTML from a website,  after pointing out on interesting box/window, where login show up (after we writing it on our keyboard):

```
<input propdescname="login" width="0" class="prePopulatedCredentials" 
type="text" size="30" maxLength="127" jQuery15206231273379102914="6" 
autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus="true"/>
```

When I try to find a box/window to put this login from VBA level – there is a problem, because there is no ID. 
I tried with Atribute “Name” but it failed `IE.Document.getElementByName("login").innerHTML = "name"`- occurs Run Time Error 438, Object doesn’t support this property or method.

The same issue is with window/box password. 
Its code line is below:

```
<input propdescname="passwd" width="0" class="prePopulatedCredentials" 
type="password" size="30" maxLength="127" autocomplete="off" 
spellcheck="false"/>
```

There is no problem with button Log on, because it has an id:

```
<input class="custombutton login_page" id="Log_On" type="submit" 
jQuery15206231273379102914="9" value="Log On"/>
IE.Document.getElementById("Log_on").Click
```

I have IE8. I read that when I install IE11 there are more possibilities. But maybe someone can help me to find solution in IE8?

[image: log on picture]

Comment: Did you try `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: That's no issue as the child element `(0)` and `(1)` can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try to see if that works for you?

```
Dim UserName As Object
Dim PW As Object

Set UserName = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("prePopulatedCredentials")(0)
UserName.Value = "Your User Name"

Set PW = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("prePopulatedCredentials")(1)
PW.Value = "Your Password"
```

Answer (score -1):

thank you for your answers. I am filled with grateful!
But in the meantime I found a line, which works! And it is:

`IE.Document.forms(0).all("login").Value = "my login"`

```
IE.Document.forms(0).all("passwd").Value = "password"
```

I try to follow this video below (guy is amazing :)), but commend regarding login / password didn't work for me.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vwb_OaT2e0